# commenting a printf statement stops output

Tags: c, function, printf

I am trying to write C code to perform some mathematical calculation. I was using a printf statement to check the print the variable. When I was done with the code, and I was getting the desired output, I commented the line out. However, after doing that, I am not getting any output. Uncommenting the line gets the desired output back.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define M 1000

const double eps = 1.110223e-16;
const double delta = 1.110223e-16;

void bisection(double (*fn)(double), double a, double b) {
    //Bisection algorithm
    double w, c, u, v, e;
    int i;
    u = (*fn)(a);
    v = (*fn)(b);
    e = b - a;

    if(signbit(u) == signbit(v)) {
        printf("Stopping due to same sign\n");
        return;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        e = e / 2;
        c = a + e;
        w = (*fn)(c);

        //Stopping conditions epsilon and delta
        if(abs(e) <= eps || abs(w) <=  delta) {
            printf("Root is %e\n", c);
            return;
        }

        if(signbit(w) == signbit(u)) {
            //Means that root lies in [c,b]
            a = c;
            u = w;
        } else {
            // Means root lies in [a, b]
            b = c;
            v = w;
        }
    }

}

double problem_a(double x) {
    return (pow(x, -1) - tan(x));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double (*fn)(double);
    fn = &problem_a;
    bisection(fn, 0.0 + eps, M_PI/2 - eps);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is: Root is 7.853982e-01
I get no output if I comment the file.

I am using the gcc compiler version 4.8.3

What can be a possible explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Your rep suggests you've been around long enough to know better than to leave your code solely in a paste-site.  Make it an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
and include the code in the question.

Comment: I could find nothing wrong with the `printf` statement.  My feeling is that you have some other problem.  If you are using Visual Studio, hit up the debugger.  It's great for problems like these.

Comment: Paste here yor code. Write what output did you expect to see and from what line.

Comment: Why are you surprised that commenting the `printf` out causes it to no longer have any effect?

Comment: I should be gettting 'Root is 7.853982e-01' in the output. If I comment out the printf in question, I get no output.

Comment: which line are you commenting out?

Comment: Works correctly in the MSVC.

Comment: I am commenting out: printf("%d\n", i);

Comment: `abs()` for `double`? Use `fabs()` (and more importantly enable warnings).

Comment: Perhaps the code is very close to working or not working depending on precision, and the printf statement changes how the compiler allocates registers

Comment: using fabs() actually fixes it for me. However, I still don't get why a printf could affect it.

Comment: For the line `if(abs(e) <= eps || abs(w) <=  delta) {`, try adding code to output all of those variables, and compare the changes between the two runs

Comment: `printf()` or not may 1) alter the optimization and 2) the precision used in calculations from `double` to `long double`.  Adjusting `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` and optimization levels may yield insight.

Comment: @Ari0nhh  When "Works correctly in the MSVC", was that with a C compilation a C++ one?

Comment: @chux With both, although C++ gets slightly different result from C. Also C compiler generates double to int truncation warning on the `abs` function, which is most likely the problem source.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `abs` without a declaration! This means that the compiler doesn't know the expected types of any arguments.

You pass a `double` argument to `abs` (which expects an `int`). This invokes undefined behaviour, which means anything can happen. And in your case it does, since you get different results if you add an unrelated `printf`.

You can fix the undefined behaviour by adding a declaration for `abs`. Indeed, if you `#include <stdlib.h>` the problem with the `printf` goes away.

This won't make your program correct, though. As pointed out by @cremno in the comments, you should use `fabs` to get the absolute value of a `double`.

So, modify the line that calls `abs` like this:

```
    if(fabs(e) <= eps || fabs(w) <=  delta) {
```

Running the modified program prints out

```
0
1
2
3
<skipping a few lines>
51
52
Root is 8.603336e-01
```